# Dex2Jar на Андроид

Tags: android, java

Всем добрый вечер.
У меня вопрос который меня мучает уже целый день! Я пытаюсь получить исходники какого нибудь приложения(вернее получаю) пропуская через dex2jar. Все классы отлично отображаются, но вот xml становятся нечитабельными и неюзабельными. Думал, что те приложения к которым я получаю доступ пропущенны через какой нить обфускатор, но методом эксперимента(то есть пропускания hello world через dex2jar) в итоге даже мои xml-ки также не читабельны.

Вопрос можно ли как нибудь получить полноценный доступ не только к классам но и к разметке?

Буду рад за помощь!

Надеюсь никто не скажет, что это не правильно и не этично брать чужие исходники, но андроид так устроен, что он сам их дает, поэтому я не виноват!

Заранее всем большое спасибо!

Comment: android дает только свои исходники, тобеж open source, в интернет хватает проектов с открытым исходным кодом и если автор сам его не выложил то это ничто иное как воровство

Comment: Я же надеялся, а все равно сказали! А можно ответ на вопрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[apktool](https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/)

Comment: Скачал, следую инструкции:

"java" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

Comment: Гм. Ну добавьте `java` в `PATH`.

Answer (score 2):

Для Android уже написали декомпилятор, но он ещё довольно "сырой". [JaDX](http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=456324)
Также можете прямо из браузера телефона зайти [сюда](http://decompileandroid.com). Загружаете туда apk'шник и ждёте минут 2-15, в зависимости от размера декомпилируемого приложения. Качество полученного кода великолепное.